# Get a count list of a nested list using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, count

I have a nested list which looks like this:

`List<List<int>> nestedList = new List<List<int>>();`

Sample data be like:
`{{1,2,3}, {4,4,2,6,3}, {1}}`

So I want to count each list and get the value to another list. For an example, the output should be : `{3,5,1}`

I have tried that using a foreach:

```
List<int> listCount = new List<int>();
foreach (List<int> list in nestedList)
{
    listCount.Add(list.Count());
}
```

Can I know how to get this output using LINQ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
var result = nestedList.Select(l => l.Count).ToList();
```

Comment: `ToList()` method should also be invoked as OP wants a list as a result :)

Comment: @Gaya3 If you look into ReSharper, you'll tend to find it suggesting refactors like this, converting `foreach` loops into LINQ statements. Great teaching tool to recognize these as you learn :)

Comment: @Kirill Thank you for your quick reply. Your answer did work!

Comment: @MichałTurczyn yes I had to use `ToList()` . Thank you

Comment: @rdev5 is ReSharper a licensed one?

Comment: @Gaya3 Yes, though they do appear to have a 30-day trial. I used it for a while but mainly for this feature; refactoring `for` loops into LINQ queries. There were a lot of times that I opted to revert their suggested refactorings, though, and ultimately learned what I needed to that I didn't feel the need to renew my subscription. 30 days should be plenty if you're using it daily.